# Limiting the number of threads to be executed

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am trying to limit the number of threads that must be executed simultaneously or to separate the elements of the array in a certain amount and send them separately (splice) but I have no idea where and how to start. The code is executing the Threads quickly and this is hindering many.

My code:

```
file = File.open('lista.txt').read
file.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "")
arr = []

file.each_line do |log|
   arr << Thread.new{

        puts login = Utils.req("GET","http://httpbin.org/GET",{
            'Host': 'api.httpbin.org',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'accept': '*/*',
        },
        false)
    }
end

arr.each(&:join)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to limit how many threads are running concurrently, use a thread pool. This creates a "pool" of worker threads and limits the number of threads running at the same time. You can write your own, or use a gem like [celluloid](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/).

```
class Whatever
  include Celluloid

  def login_request
    Utils.req(
      "POST",
      "http://httpbin.org/post",
      {
        'Host': 'api.httpbin.org',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept': '*/*',
      },
      false
    )
  end
end

# Only 5 threads will run at a time.
pool = Whatever.pool(size: 5)

file.each_line do |log|
  split = log.split("|")
  id = split[0]
  number = split[1]

  # If there's a free working in the pool, this will execute immediately.
  # If not, it will wait until there is a free worker.
  pool.login_request
end
```

Comment: I used your code as an example and code appears to run 1 thread at a time, synchronously

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). Here's a very basic one using [`Queue`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Queue.html):

```
queue = Queue.new

pool = Array.new(5) do
  Thread.new do
    loop do
      line = queue.pop
      break if line == :stop

      # do something with line, e.g.
      # id, number = line.split('|')
      # Utils.req(...)
    end
  end
end
```

It creates 5 threads and stores them in an array for later reference. Each thread runs a loop, calling [`Queue#pop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Queue.html#pop-method) to fetch a line from the queue. If the queue is empty, `pop` will suspend the thread until data becomes available. So initially, the threads will just sit there waiting for work to come:

```
queue.num_waiting  #=> 5
pool.map(&:status) #=> ["sleep", "sleep", "sleep", "sleep", "sleep"]
```

Once the thread has retrieved a line, it will process it (to be implemented) and fetch a new one (or fall asleep again if there is none). If the line happens to be the symbol `:stop`, the thread will break the loop and terminate. (a very pragmatic approach)

To fill the queue, we can use a simple loop in our main thread:

```
file.each_line { |line| queue << line }
```

Afterwards, we push 5 `:stop` symbols to the end of the queue and then wait for the threads to finish:

```
pool.each { queue << :stop }
pool.each(&:join)
```

At this point, no threads are waiting for the queue – they all terminated normally:

```
queue.num_waiting  #=> 0
pool.map(&:status) #=> [false, false, false, false, false]
```

---

Note that `Queue` isn't limited to strings or symbols. You can push any Ruby object to it. So instead of pushing the raw line, you could push the pre-processed data:

```
file.each_line do |line|
  id, number = line.split('|')
  queue << [id, number]
end
```

This way, your threads don't have to know about the log format. They can just work on `id` and `number`:

```
loop do
  value = queue.pop
  break if value == :stop

  id, number = value
  # do something with id and number
end
```

Instead of writing your own thread pool, you could of course use one of the various concurrency gems.